# Formulae/strategy for performance of deductive reasoning on a Platonic solid?

Tags: geometry, logic, platonic-solids

I have a Platonic solid (in this case, a dodecahedron), and I have twelve names that I must put on this dodecahedron. I have an incomplete list of who is next to who, and I'm trying to fill in the rest based on context clues. It seems like this would be a perfect problem for deductive reasoning, but the methods I learned in school are decidedly two-dimensional. Are there any formulas or techniques for applying this concept to a 3D shape?

Comment: Please provide the exact problem you are trying to solve. What is the "incomplete list of who is next to who[m]", and what are the remaining "context clues"?

Comment: I'm not asking for the solution, I'm asking for proper tools on how to solve it, or at least terms I can Google. I'll provide more detail, though.

Comment: Would using the Schlegel diagram for of a dodecahedron help to $2$ dimensionalise it for you ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlegel_diagram#Examples

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit That...is a very elegant solution. I can most certainly use normal, everyday deductive reasoning on something like that. Put it up as an answer and I'll approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would using the Schlegel diagram for of a dodecahedron help to $2$ dimensionalise it for you ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlegel_diagram#Examples

[image]